# Experiences with Autonomy IDOL

Tags: untagged

We're currently looking at implementing Autonomy IDOL in our environment.  Does anyone have any recommendations or gotchas that we should be aware of?  Are other companies using IDOL successfully?

I'm curious to get some real-world impressions beyond the case studies we've been provided with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently implementing IDOL for one of our customers. It is a very powerful product.

I would recommend:

- to start small. Maybe only with just one connector and IDOL and a small sample of data. You will better see the kind of problems (technical issues, business decisions...) you will have to deal with. Then increase the complexity of your architecture.
- to be careful with security issues. Test the security configuration of your connectors and of your OGS. What happens if you change the security on a document, on the database... ? Is the change replicated on IDOL?
- consider your project as a development project and do test your developments / configurations.
- Do the business analysis considering the data fields. Which fields to search /display, what will be the type of the field in IDOL (index, parametric, date, numeric...) ?
- If you plan to develop a custom GUI, maybe start it once the IDOL server configuration is fully tested.
- Build a team with people who know the product and have already worked with it.
  If you have any question do not hesitate,

Have fun :-)

J.

Answer (score 0):

One of our customers use it, all I can really say it that is is Python, and thus can use only one cpu, which can be an issue. Hangs once in a great while.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Autonomy DRE and IDOL last 10 years and it's amazing technology. Connectors and DIH DAH are powerful products if you are looking for smart technology. With Autonomy IDOL there is no stupid users who are searching wrong keywords. Your results are correct even if your keyword search is wrong.

http://www.eurosom.com